# TypeScript asset manager

Tags: assets, typescript

I use node.js connect/express.

Does anyone know an assets manager that supports on the fly compilation and minification of TypeScript source code?

Any idea how to call the compiler programmatically?

I've been using [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) which is build on top of [Snockets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/snockets). Shouldn't be that hard to implement once I figure how to compile a **.ts** resource.

Answer (score 1):

From reading through the tsc.js code, it looks like there's a `TypeScript.TypeScriptCompiler(outfile, errout, new TypeScript.NullLogger(), this.compilationSettings);` function you could hook into. The code is on Codeplex, under an Apache license, and it's modular. Since TypeScript can be compiled to target CommonJS modules, it should be fairly straightforward to hack it into express.

Comment: Looking at the unit tests, they seem to have what I am looking for in Harness.ts. Investigating

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer yet, but I found this project: which exposes the TypeScript compiler.

https://bitbucket.org/nxt/node-typescript-wrapper